# trunc даты и времени

Tags: oracle, дата, время, конвертация

Есть таблица, в которой есть столбец с типом TIMESTAMP. Данные в нем подобны этому: 27-FEB-22 01.40.18.000000 AM

Как урезать эти данные до секунд? Ожидаемый результат: 27-FEB-22 01:40:18 AM

СУБД - ORACLE

Comment: Какая у вас СУБД?

Comment: Забыл уточнить. 
ORACLE

Comment: Эээ... ```CAST( value AS TIMESTAMP(0) )```? ну или TO_CHAR() с требуемым форматом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип date содержит данные до секунд
Перевести можно так:

```
select
....
cast(old_timestamp_column as date) as new_date_column,
....
from ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
replace ('27-FEB-22 01.40.18.000000 AM', '.000000','') as Resultat
from dual

RESULTAT             
---------------------
27-FEB-22 01.40.18 AM
```

если просто текст?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]